# RASA core server giving 403 error

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have started rasa core server as in doc https://rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/
But whenever I am trying to make a call from any rest client getting 403 error.

But When I do GET of localhost:5005 I'm getting proper response as **hello from Rasa Core: 0.9.0a3**

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with windows

in insomnia send the post as a JSON body with content

```
{
   "query": "Hi"
}
```

in curl give `curl -X POST localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond -d "{\"query\":\"hi\"}" | python -mjson.tool`

I am giving this answer thinking you are using windows. I had the same issue and this worked for me in windows.